# Object and subject for adverb phrases

Tags: grammar

example:"  I  love watching movie on netflix on computer in my living room."

what is the subject object relationship for the adverb phrases in "on netflix on computer in my living room"

netflix is subject, and everything else are object?

What about "on netflix on computer in my living room" to "I  love watching movie "?

"on netflix on computer in my living room" is a object for the "I  love watching movie "as the subject?

Comment: There's nothing inherently ungrammatical about chaining together multiple preposition-based elements in English, even if they all use the *same* preposition. So *I'll be **at** work **at** the office **at** 10 o'clock tomorrow* and *He doesn't like to be **on** the phone **on** the toilet **on** Sundays* are both syntactically fine, even if that second one is *semantically* a bit quirky..

Answer (score 2):

It's verbs that have subjects. The subject of your first verb, *love*, is *I*, and the object is the gerund phrase "watching movie." Within the gerund phrase, *watching* is the verb, and its object is *movie*.

Everything else is a triple of prepositional phrases, each of which functions adverbially, as each modifies *watching*. As for *Netflix*, it's the object of the preposition *on*. Likewise, *computer* is the object of (the second occurrence of) *on*, and the noun phrase "living room" is the object of *in*.